# I forgot my keystore credentials ,how can I submit an update now?

Tags: android, android-keystore

So I just posted an app about 15 days before and now I want to upload a new update but while generating the Signed Apk Android studio is asking me for key store credentials... and I read that I have to provide the same credentials that I used on first submission (I did not remember anything about that)

Somehow I managed to get an backup of keystore.store file (which is stored at my project's directory inside a folder named KEY_STORE ) now when I'm putting the suspected alias and passwords I'm getting this error :

***Failed to read key from `myalias` from store /mypath/for/keystore cannot recover key***

Now what I can do to get back my credentials ???

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover credentials.
The only way to do this is to try a tool like
http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/
I've never use it.
I think it will try to brute force your credentials.

UPDATE:
I've tested it and it works.
Go to
http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/
Add java files download from the url to a new Java Project (ex. using ItelliJ IDEA)
Add the keystore file to the root of the project
Add this option to program args in this way
-m 1 -k keystorefilename
Run the program
Alternatively, run the jar download from the url and use the same args.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro, no way to recover now, you have to have the correct credentials. All you can do is publish a new application in the same name.